# How can I assign a string a range of numbers?

Tags: python, string

If I wanted `mystring = (any number between 0-9)` is there any way to assign a value like this to a string?

If I had something similar to this :

```
mystring = "7676-[0-9]-*"
```

I would want this in theory to be equal to 7676-5-0 and also 7676-9-100 etc.
The reason I want this is because later in my script I will be writing a conditional statement such as:

```
if mystring == yourstring:
    print('something cool')
else:
    print('not cool')
```

where `yourstring` is equal to a number such as `7676-3-898` where it would equal `mystring` or `7777-7-8` where it would not equal `mystring`

Comment: Sounds like a regexp problem

Comment: `if re.match('7676-[0-9]-[0-9]+'', mystring)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html).

As an example, here is something that should be working for you:

```
import re
# 7676 + one digit between 0 and 9 + at least one digit between 0 and 9 (can be more)
pattern = "7676-[0-9]-[0-9]+"
```

and later in your code:

```
if re.match(pattern, "7676-9-100"):
    print("something cool")
else:
    print("not cool")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to regex version, you can achieve this in Pythonic way using split() function in Python:

```
    mystring = "7676-5-*"
    if '0' <= mystring.split('-')[1] <= '9':
        print('something cool')
    else:
        print('not cool')
```